# The $in operator inside $project, $match or find()

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a find query that uses $in to check whether the specified array is contained within the collection string array:

`db.Doc.find({ tags: { '$in': ['tag1','tag2'] } })`

I am in the process of refactoring this query to use the aggregation framework, but I can't find the equivalent `$in` comparison operator at the `$project` or `$match` aggregation stages.

Is it possible to use the `$in` comparison operator at the `$project` or `$match` stages of an aggregation query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: yes, but not as you would expect. It is possible to use the *$in* operator at the $project or $match stages of an aggregation query, but the usage and the purpose aren't quite the same in each.

There are two extremely different types of the "same" *$in* operator (making a semantic confusion):

1. **Non-aggregational [*$in*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)**: Usually narrows down the results, like a filter. It has no way to add information to the result set, if it doesn't match. Can be used both within [***find()***](http://collection%20method) collection method and inside the aggregational (quite confusing semantic ah?) [***$match***](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/).
2. **Aggregational [*$in*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/)**: Usually adds boolean information to the result set, can be used as a logic expression inside [*$cond*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/), and might also remove some results when is used with [*$redact*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/). Can be used in [***$project***](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), [*$addFields*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/), etc. (but cannot (!) be used within *find()* or *$match*). The structure is: `{ $in: [ <needle expression>, <array haystack expression> ] }`, and all of this grey line becomes either **true** or **false** (I used PHP's documentation's in_array needle-heystack semantic to better explain). So, `{ $in [ 'foo', [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ] ] }` is **true** because foo is inside the array.
   However, in the previous non-aggregational *$in*, the `{ maybeFooField: { $in: [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ] } }` structure query simply narrows down the result set, and it doesn't result in a boolean true or false.

---

Going back to your refactoring, the question is what are your intended results? Why did you switch to the aggregation framework from the beginning?

If you only want to narrow down or filter out the result set, and then use some other aggregation computations, use the simple **non-aggregational *$in*** operator.

```
db.Doc.aggregate([
{ $match: { tags: {$in: ['tag1','tag2'] } } } // non-aggregational $in
])
```

However, if you want to add information based on the existence or absence of certain tags, use the **aggregational *$in*** operator.

```
db.Doc.aggregate([
{ $project: { hasAnyTag: {$in: [$tags, ['tag1', 'tag2'] ] } } } // aggregational $in
])
```

Note, you have more aggregational operators to play with arrays, like: [$setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) and [$setIsSubset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/).

Answer (score 0):

The query: `db.Doc.find({ tags: { '$in': ['tag1','tag2'] } })` is equivalent to:

```
db.Doc.aggregate([
{$match:{tags: {$in: ['tag1','tag2'] }}}

])
```

And when u use `$in` at projection like below:

```
db.Doc.aggregate([
{$project:{tags: {$in: ['tag1','tag2'] }}}

])
```

Result will be `tags:true` or `tags:false` depending upon whether there's match or not.